# Ajax cannot send form id to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I have a slight problem with ajax. So first I'm gonna show you my actions.

Form:

```
<form id="QuestionForm">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Body, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Body" }) 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Text" })
</form>
```

Here's my script and ajax code:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var data = $('#QuestionForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Survey/AddQuestion",
        data: {data, @Model.Survey.Id},
        success: function () {
            $("#AddQuestion").modal("hide");
            //alert("Survey Added");
            location.reload();
        }
    })

})
```

Here's my controller action:

```
public JsonResult AddQuestion(SurveyQuestion model, int id) 
{  
    SurveyQuestion question = new SurveyQuestion();
    question.Body = model.Body;
    question.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    question.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
    question.Priority = 0;
    question.SurveyId = id;
    question.Text = model.Text;
    question.Type = QuestionType.Text;

    _db.SurveyQuestions.Add(question);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(question, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I didn't fill out every part of the code, some of it is hardcoded, because I'm going to do the actions later. But the problem is with sending two things.
If I don't send the Id and delete Id from the controller, it sends the serialized model well, but If I send them both, it gets the Id, but it doesn't get the model sent to him (text and body is null). How do I fix this?

Comment: can't you pass id as a querystring

Comment: can you please paste that as an answer? thank you

Comment: did it and you can add FromUri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Survey/AddQuestion",
        // Add id like query string parameter like below
        data: $('#QuestionForm').serialize() + '&id=' + @Model.Survey.Id,
        success: function() {
            $("#AddQuestion").modal("hide");
            //alert("Survey Added");
            location.reload();
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass id as query string parameter

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
  var data = $('#QuestionForm').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Survey/AddQuestion?id=" + '@Model.Survey.Id',
    data: {data, @Model.Survey.Id},
    success: function () {
        $("#AddQuestion").modal("hide");
        //alert("Survey Added");
        location.reload();
    }
})
})
```

In controller use **FromUri** attribute before the parameter

```
public JsonResult AddQuestion(SurveyQuestion model,[FromUri]int id)
{

    SurveyQuestion question = new SurveyQuestion();
    question.Body = model.Body;
    question.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    question.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
    question.Priority = 0;
    question.SurveyId = id;
    question.Text = model.Text;
    question.Type = QuestionType.Text;

    _db.SurveyQuestions.Add(question);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(question, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put id in the url

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
  var data = $('#QuestionForm').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Survey/AddQuestion?id=@Model.Survey.Id",
    data: {data},
    success: function () {
        $("#AddQuestion").modal("hide");
        //alert("Survey Added");
        location.reload();
    }
  })

})
```

Comment: i am sorry,i  forget the id param behind "?",

Answer (score 0):

Try this, passing multiple parameters in post or you can pass using querystring as shown in other answers

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var data = $('#QuestionForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Survey/AddQuestion",
        data: {model : data, id: @Model.Survey.Id},
        success: function () {
            $("#AddQuestion").modal("hide");
            //alert("Survey Added");
            location.reload();
        }
    })

})
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ActionName(SurveyQuestion model, int id)
{
   Your Code .......
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, I've tried this, but I already got an answer to my question, thanks anyway!